# Can't get promise to work with external function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to wrap my head around the javascript promises since I need them in a project I'm working on. I've tried several things but never got it to work.

Here's the problem:

I have a function that connects to a server via websockets, grabs certain infos and delivers them as an object.
As this is async, I need to wait until this process has finished to go on with the infos I got.

This is the global function for getting the infos:

```
function getInfos(par1, par2) {

    // Open Websocket connection, ask for infos and wait for Answer/Message.

    OnMessage: function (aEvent, aToken) {
        if (aToken == "JustAString") {

            // Does this work this way? I need to get the "aToken" to the "MyCalltoServer" Function that called this mess here
            return aToken;

           // Tried this to resolve the promise created in the other script.
            resolve(MyCallToServer);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I tried to create a promise with my existing getInfos function.

```
var promiseResolve, promiseReject;

var MyCallToServer = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

promiseResolve = resolve;
promiseReject = reject;

getInfos(par1,par2);


});

MyCallToServer.then(function(){
    console.log("done");
    console.log(aToken);
})
```

Long story short - it doesn't work at all. Any help is greatly appreciated. The thing is I can't change the construction of 
the getInfos function since it's way to complex already (300 cases for different answers). So I thought maybe there's a way
to include the promise resolving in it?

Any Help is greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: You create `promiseResolve` and `promiseReject` though do not pass the functions to `getInfos` - neither function is called, `resolve` is undefined within `getInfos`.

Comment: how would the call look like? getInfos(par1,par2,promiseResolve) ?

Comment: You can't have `getInfos` return it's own promise?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know :-) Honestly I'm not understanding the principle completely yet. Would you mind giving me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Not certain why `OnMessage` is within `getInfos` or why the syntax is

```
OnMessage: function (aEvent, aToken) {}
```

You can return a `Promise` from `getInfos()` call, pass `aToken` to `resolve()`, include error handling function passed to `.catch()`

```
function getInfos(par1, par2) {

  // Open Websocket connection, ask for infos and wait for Answer/Message.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    function OnMessage(aEvent, aToken) {
        if (aToken == "JustAString") {
            resolve(aToken);
        }
    };
    OnMessage()
  })
}

function MyCallToServer(par1, par1) {
  return getInfos(par1, par2)
}

function handleMyCallToServer(aToken) {
  console.log("done");
  console.log(aToken);
}

function handleMyCallToServerErroir(err) {
  console.log("error");
  console.err(err);
}

MyCallToServer(1, 2)
.then(handleMyCallToServer)
.catch(handleMyCallToServerError)
```

Comment: The "OnMessage" is a callback from another function within the getInfos() function that returns the answer from the server. I just shortened that out here.

I have to place the promise / resolve somehow in there.

Comment: The `Promise` is resolved within `OnMessage` at code at Answer

Comment: I can't get it to work, console tells me 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'. The "OnMessage" is no function but a callback from another function within the getInfos() function.

Comment: This is how it looks here:

else if (aToken.reqType == "xyz") {
 lWSC.close();

 return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        resolve(aToken);

 })

}

Comment: Are you able to change `OnMessage`?

Comment: not really.. i was hoping for a simple way to add another line of code into that if else block to resolve the promise that has been set in another script at another place in the app

Comment: Given the code at OP you can pass `promiseResolve` and `promiseReject`, which do not appear to be called at current JavaScript, to `getInfos`. What is the purpose of `MyCallToServer`? Where is `resolve` defined? `aToken` is undefined within `.then()` chained to `MyCallToServer` if `aToken` is not global. There are several issue with code at Question, though possibly adjustable to meet requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Promises can't be reused. Creating a global promise variable to be resolved/rejected from a parameterized function that can be called multiple times is tantamount to setting up non-reentrant, asynchronous code. Do not go there.

A classic way to provide asynchronous data is to use a call back function taking two parameters, one of which is set according to the final result of the operation:

```
 function getInfos( par1, par2, callBack) {

     //  in asynchronous code that successfully delivers dataObject 

          callBack( false, dataObject); // valid data
          return; // from asynchronous service code

     //  in asynchronous code that detected an error

          callBack( error) // no valid data
          return; // from asynchronous service code

  }
```

which is called with a callback function patterned on:

```
  function callBack( err, data) {
      if( err) {
      //   the bad news
      }
      if( data) {
      // the good news.
      }
  }
```

Alternatively you can promisify `getInfos` by returning a pending promise that is resolved or rejected after network operations have taken place. This can be achieved by placing all the code (for `getInfos`) in an ES6 promise executor function which is called *synchronously* during promise construction:

```
function getInfos( par1, par2) {
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        // initiate getInfos things with supplied par1, par2 values

        // in asynchronous code that successfully created dataObject

             resolve( dataObject);
             return; // from asynchronous service code

        // in asynchronous code that failed
             reject( new Error( "error text");
             return; // from asynchronous service code
    });
}
```

Some libraries provide both mechanisms by always returning a promise (which need not be used) besides conditionally calling a callback if one is provided. I would suggest simply promisifying `getInfos` in this case.

---

Edit.  The code in comment replicates a JQuery "deferred" object with a variety of deconstructed promise object components and variables. This is a kludge I do not recommend pursuing.

A simpler solution is to first modify `getInfos` to return a promise then  replace

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var promiseResolve, promiseReject;
    var FunctionThatCallsServerFunction = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       promiseResolve = resolve;
       promiseReject = reject;
       getInfos(par1,par2);
    });
    FunctionThatCallsServerFunction.then(function() {
        console.log("done"); // aToken should be received from the ServerFunction
        console.log(aToken);
    })
})
```

with

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    getInfos( par1, par2)
    .then(function( aToken) {
        console.log("done");
        console.log(aToken);
    })
    .catch( function( err) {
        console.log("An error occurred: ");
        console.log( err);
    });
})
```

which uses the promise returned by `getInfos` directly. Notice that

- the value used to fulfill a promise is passed as the argument value to a fulfillment handler supplied with `.then`, and
- generally include a catch clause to avoid "unhandled promise rejection" exceptions being thrown by Promise software in the event of an error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I I still have a little problem understanding some things: I edited the getInfos() like you said and in the if else loop where i need the promise to be fullfiled, i added the resolve(dataObject). For what stands the "dataObject"? In the loop I get an Object (aToken) which I need to pass to the function that called this function. In the other file where I call the function this is how my code looks like. Am I doing it right?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

    var promiseResolve, promiseReject;

    var FunctionThatCallsServerFunction = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        promiseResolve = resolve;
        promiseReject = reject;

        getInfos(par1,par2);
    });

    FunctionThatCallsServerFunction.then(function(){

        console.log("done");

        // aToken should be received from the ServerFunction
        console.log(aToken);

    })

});

Comment: The question describes the operation as "grabs them as infos and delivers them as an object": the delivered object is the one I refer to as "dataObject" in the abstract. If `aToken` is the object in reality, use that instead. Note that you can't pass the data back to the function that called 'getInfos' because the data is obtained asynchronously (I presume) and that function will have long since returned. You pass the data on to a promise reaction handler (supplied with `then`) which does something with the data.